# Argparse with a positional and optional argument (Positional with range of values)

Tags: python, argparse

I want my code to be able to capture one positional  "-y" and one optional "-tab"
For the former one it takes value only `1, 2, 3`

So that I can do

```
mycode.py -tab -y 1
mycode.py -y1

or

mycode.py -tab -y 2
mycode.py -y2

or

mycode.py -tab -y 3
mycode.py -y3
```

And if we give value other than 3 it will raise error.

What's the way to do it in Python?

This is my attempt:

```
# Setup argument paring
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Some description.")
parser.add_argument("-tab","--tabular", help="Some task", action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("-y","--yell", nargs=1, help="Type of fold change to show")
args = parser.parse_args()


tabular = False
type = 1
if args.tabular:
    tabular=True

if args.yell == 1:
    type = '1'
elif args.yell == 2:
    type = 2
elif args.yell == 3:
    type = 3
else:
    raise Exception('Incorrect type, max 3')
```

It has 3 problems:

1. always the value of `type = 1`
2. never raises error if I gave -y 4 (or other than 1,2,3).
3. `-y` is located as optional (it should be positional)

**Update:**

Enabling positional argument for `-y`, still doesn't work.

The full code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# Python 2.7.
import sys
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Some description.")
parser.add_argument("-tab","--tabular", help="Some task", action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("-y", help="Type of fold change to show", choices=range(1,4), required=True, type=int)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

The command line:

```
$ python mycode.py -h 
usage: mycode.py [-h] [-tab] [-y {1,2,3}]

Some description.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help       show this help message and exit
  -tab, --tabular  Some task
  -y {1,2,3}       Type of fold change to show
```

My expected results:

```
$ python mycode.py -h 
usage: mycode.py [-h] [-tab] [-y {1,2,3}]

Some description.

positional arguments:
-y {1,2,3}       Type of fold change to show    

optional arguments:
-h, --help       show this help message and exit
-tab, --tabular  Some task
```

Press ENTER or type command to continue

Comment: not sure what you're doing, but comparing numeric const using "is" operator seems wrong. Are you not suppose to use equality operator for that?

Comment: you can just print the type and value of args.yell, my guess is that the value is string instead of int. Also, your 'type' variable is not consistent, sometimes it stores string '1' and on the other two cases, it stores int (2 and 3)

Answer (score 1):

General things:

Don't use `is` to compare numerical equality, use `==`.

Optional command line arguments should be prepended by two dashes.  Likewise, positional arguments should **not** be prepended by two dashes.

---

When you `add_argument`, you can specify the `choices` kwarg.

```
parser.add_argument("-y","--yell", help="Type of fold change to show", choices=range(1,4), type=int)
```

This will complain if `-y` is specified outside 1 to 3, inclusive.  I added the `type=int` directive so that `args.yell` will be an `int` instead of a string.

**Note** that I left off the `nargs=1` kwarg.  Specifying `nargs=1` means that `args.yell` is *a list with one element*, not an `int`.  That is the source of a bug in your code: `[1]` does not equal `1`.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I make "-y" to be `positional` instead of `optional`.

Comment: @neversaint don't prepend it with two dashes.

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work. 1) I remove the "--yell" it is still optional and 2) I tried -y1 -y4. All raises error. Can you give the example of running code? Very sorry for the trouble.

Comment: If you want to keep the `-` semantics with your current code, just specify `required=True` kwarg.  And when you call it, it's `-y 3`, not `-y3`, the latter won't parse.

Comment: Thanks the problem 2) solved, but not 1). I tried `required=True` for yell 
`parser.add_argument("-y", help="Type of fold change to show", choices=range(1,4), type=int,required=True)` still optional and not positional.

Comment: please check update. I tried still doesn't work. Did I miss anything.

Comment: You didn't add `required=True` at all.

Comment: Oops, sorry. Updated. Now added `required=True` when missing it correctly showed `mycode.py: error: argument -y is required`. But when I do `python mycode.py -h`, it still doesn't show under "positional arguments".

Comment: That's because it's **not** positional - it's named.  You would specify a positional argument like `myscript.py 4`.  If you want to make it positional, drop the leading `-` from `-y`, and use it in a positional manner.